# Symbol from C file is not being added even though the MakeFile includes its object file

Tags: android, c, makefile, ffmpeg, android-ndk

I'm trying to build libavformat with this [MAKEFILE](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/VG2MzFKMry/). Although the makefile includes `avio.o` file in its build instruction but it doesn't add any symbol for the functions that are declared on the header file `url.h`. Source folder which includes the `avio.c, avio.h and url.h` files can be found [HERE](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/dir_c323f0049949ddd42f5d8cc7327305d9.html).

The nm command for `avio.o` returns

`nm: avio.o: File format not recognized`

`file` command on `avio.o` shows the following output

```
avio.o: LLVM IR bitcode
```

I have checked the nm command on the generated libavformat.so and did not find any symbols for the functions declared on the `url.h` file

I have been stuck on this for two days. Could not figure out how to solve this problem!

Calling the `ff_check_interrupt` method and results in

> undefined reference to 'ff_check_interrupt'

Configurations and flags.

- FFmpeg Configuration File: [Config.h](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zSpnTYZKYY/)
- FFmpeg Root MakeFile: [Root MakeFile](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/cyRwZmYb9Q/)
- CC, CXX, CFLAGS, LDFLAGS: [FLAGS](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/prpPqgQsHW/)

Comment: Did you check with `nm`?

Comment: Yes, I did with the following nm command `nm -gD libavformat.so`. But the result doesn't contain `ff_check_interrupt`

Comment: Sorry I have given wrong information when started the bounty. FFMPEG actually builds successfully. Meaning all the `so` files are successfully built. But when we are trying to call some functions in the `libavformat.so` through `jni` then its not finding that function on `libavformat.so` although makefile included it when building the `so`. The `jni` actually first calls some function in a c source file and that c source file calls that missing function of libavformat.so. And here we are stuck.

Comment: Have you marked your ff_check_interrupt function as `__attribute__((visibility("default")))`?

Comment: No we didn't mark it with that attribute. We see that there is another shared library named `libavformat.so.58` which contains the missing symbol. In the build log we see that this `so` is stripped and turned into `libavformat.so` which doesn't have the symbol. Is this strip command causing the problem? How can we remove it? Thank you for your comment.

Comment: It´s kind of hard to see from the Makefile, but when you run it, does the invocation of the compiler in the link step (that is, the command with all the .o files) list the avio.o file after the .o file where you´re attempting to reference `ff_check_interrupt`?

Comment: Libraries are sometimes stripped of symbols, which may be causing the JNI to not find your function. Can you try removing the strip from the root Makefile? eg look at this https://github.com/priamm/FFmpeg-n4.0/blob/e13f451904782effb22860d45bbe3b37c4e7b496/Makefile#L100 . Change line 100 and line 193 in this case

Comment: It will be useful if you edit your post with the options you pass to configure

Comment: @KarthikSriram I tried commenting the `$(STRIP) -o $@ $<` from the MakeFile like you said. But still, the symbol is being stripped. I have updated the post and added the `Config.h`, `Root MakeFile`, and `Flag` that we are using.

Answer (score 0):

First off, a function declared by `url.h` should be defined in `url.c`, not in `avio.c`.

Second the only use of the `ff_check_interrupt` in `avoi.c` is within a static inline function, so indeed the toolchain is likely optimizing this symbol away.

I think what's occurring for you is that the toolchain making the decision that this is only used in this compilation unit.

Moving the definition of `ff_check_interrupt` to 'url.c' should resolve the issue. This is a library though, so out of your control.

However, this doesn't answer why [thousands of users on Github](https://github.com/search?q=ff_check_interrupt&type=code) have this same library in their code. I'd suggest comparing your Makefile against those (e.g. first search return is [this one](https://github.com/priamm/FFmpeg-n4.0/blob/e13f451904782effb22860d45bbe3b37c4e7b496/libavformat/Makefile).

Comment: We moved the function definitions from the `avio.c` to `url.c`. But the result is the same. We compared the make file you provided with our makefile and they are almost identical.

Comment: The name of the C file is irrelevant. It´s perfectly fine do define symbols declared in url.h in avio.c.